# Add data to listview

Tags: android, listview

When i moved my app from eclipse to android studio. i have error in this part of code : 
`AddList.Add(Add);`
**Addlist is a Listview widget**

```
 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                            Advertisement Add=new Advertisement();
                            JSONObject jRealObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Set the Value
                            Add.setTitle(jRealObject.getString("Title"));
                            Add.setLikes(jRealObject.getString("Likes"));
                            //Add Data to List
                            AddList.Add(Add);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some data about the error?

Comment: What error are you getting ? Null POinter exception ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show the code of your adapter. 
I think that after adding your Advertisement at your AddList you should notify to your adapter that data set changed function.

```
adapter.notifiDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i try to add notifiDataSetChanged() function but it's not work!

Comment: it's work well in eclipse...but not work in Android Studio

Comment: i found the error ....Now i use the ArrayList Variable instead Listview Variable and work very well...a lot thanks Max Pinto

Comment: you are welcome, so if you resolve your problem, should close the thread of the conversation, accept some  anwer to do that. Regards